# How can I configure webpack + aurelia to use server-side templates

Tags: razor, webpack, aurelia

I'm trying to get my app to use server-side templates(.cshtml) and have tried the recommended approach of overriding the `ViewLocator.prototype.convertOriginToViewUrl`.

Unfortunately it doesn't seem to work with webpack, as hinted by [@EisenbergEffect](https://stackoverflow.com/users/24146/eisenbergeffect). on my previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43044527/custom-view-location-in-aurelia)

I have a route that returns html and I want to use that as my view.

Example here in ASP.NET MVC

```
    public ActionResult Template(string view)
    {
        return View(string.Format("~/Views/Shared/ClientTemplates/{0}.cshtml", view));
    }
```

Aurelia code

```
    import {ViewLocator} from 'aurelia-framework';

    export function configure(aurelia) {
       aurelia.use
         .standardConfiguration()
         .developmentLogging();

        ViewLocator.prototype.convertOriginToViewUrl = (origin) => {
          return "/common/template?view=" + origin.moduleId;
        };

        aurelia.start().then(a => a.setRoot());
     }
```

Result `Error: Cannot find module './/common/template?view=app'`.

Running the route `/common/template?view=app` in a browser returns, as expected, the markup that resides in the `app.cshtml`

How can I configure webpack + aurelia to use server-side templates?

Comment: I know that my comment doesn't help anything with your question, but why  you want to render your views with asp.net? What are the benefits?

Comment: You can check this question, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37870145/customizing-aurelia-to-use-cshtml

Comment: @FabioLuz Soemexamples, different view structure depending on logged in user, the usage of .resx resources and so on...

Comment: @janmvtrinidad That doesn't work when you use webpack,

Comment: @PeterWikström I see... Well, you could do all of this only using aurelia, which would be a lot faster. This doesn't answer your question but I think you could give it a try

Comment: Thanks, I have a pretty good idea how to do it with pure Aurelia code but if you have a project with a lot of legacy code it would be nice to just reuse the existing resources,...

Comment: @PeterWikström, did you get this working? Read somewhere that it may be possible to write a dynamic rest loader for webpack but not found anything yet.

Comment: @LunchBaron nope, I haven't found any solution for this. I will check out the dynamic rest loader stuff 